# How to loop using mediaplayer - Android

Tags: java, android, loops, media-player

How do i play my audio files in sequence from my sdcard? I have two classes, one for results another for the actual rendering. ***Is my while loop in the correct place?***

```
public void DoIt() {  
while(!mp.isPlaying()){


AudioRenderer mr = new AudioRenderer();
mp = mr.AudioRenderer(filePath);
if(mp!=null){
mp.start(); 
if(!mp.isPlaying())
    break;
}
}

if(mp == null){ *write results logic*}



private class AudioRenderer extends Activity {
private MediaPlayer AudioRenderer(String filePath) {


MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
File location = new File(filePath);

Uri path = Uri.fromFile(location);
ExtentionSeperator media = new ExtentionSeperator(filePath, '.');
if(ext.equals("mp3") || ext.equals("wav")|| ext.equals("ogg")|| ext.equals("mid")|| 
ext.equals("flac")){


        mp= MediaPlayer.create(this, path);}
                 return mp;}
```

My app just keeps writing the results without waiting for the first one to stop playing first. I want it to Render -> Play -> Wait for whole audio to stop playing -> Write result into file -> Next file.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

if you want them to play one after the other

there is an event in mediaplayer

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener()
```

which will fire once the first file is complete. here you can play the next file.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
class MediaDemo extends Activity{
  public static MediaPlayer myplayer=new MediaPlayer();
  public static ArrayList<String> pathlist=new ArrayList<String>();
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
       myplayer.reset();
       myplayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){
         public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
             pathlist.remove(0);
             if(pathlist.size()>=1){
                 myplayer.reset();
                 playAudio();
            }
         }
     });
 pathlist.add("filename");
 if(!myplayer.isPlaying()){
    playAudio();
 }
}
public void playAudio(){
     try{
         if(pathlist.size()>=1){
           String path=pathlist.get(0);
            myplayer.setDataSource(path);
            myplayer.prepare();
            myplayer.start();
         }
     }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

}

Comment: this is fine but i can't use mediaplayer.prepare, i need to use  mp= MediaPlayer.create(this, path);

Comment: no problem,first declare the Mediaplayer variable. then create the object using your technic(mp=MediaPlayer.creat(this,path);,don't call mp.prepare(),instead call mp.start();

Comment: No,no as in  mp= MediaPlayer.create(this, path); won't work inside the onCompletionListener method.

Answer (score 1):

according to your code you have to use the mp.setOnCompletionListener(). In this give path for the next file which you want to play.